# How do I stop a single button from hiding my textbox during a specific event?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two questions:

1) Is this the correct way to make my default value = 0 for variables, then pass a value given by the user into that variable?

```
protected void btnCheck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblYesNo.Text = "";
        //default int values are set to 0
        int remainder = 0;
        int guess = 0;

        remainder = int.Parse(txtRemainder.Text);

        guess = int.Parse(txtAnswer.Text);
        answer = (int)Session["answer"];
        if (guess == answer)
        {
            lblYesNo.Text = lblYesNo.Text + "Correct!";
        }
        else
        {
            lblYesNo.Text = lblYesNo.Text + "Try Again..";
        }
    }//END Check Answer
```

2) how can I stop the Check_Click(submit button) from hiding the txtRemainder(textbox)? The reason it 'auto-hides' now is because I set the default value to 'txtRemainder.Visible = false;' in the Page_Load, which will make it hide unless the math problem is division. When I click on the btnDiv_Click(divide button) it resets it to 'txtRemainder.Visible = true;', because this provides a division question to be solved.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class BasicMath : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    int number1;
    int number2;
    int answer;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtRemainder.Visible = false;
    }

    protected void GetRandom()
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        number1 = rand.Next(0, 10);
        number2 = rand.Next(0, 10);
        txtAnswer.Text = "";
        txtRemainder.Text = "";
        lblYesNo.Text = "";
    }//END Get Random Number

    protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GetRandom();
        lblEquation.Text = number1.ToString() + " + " + number2.ToString();
        answer = number1 + number2;
        Session["answer"] = answer;
    }//END Addition Button

    protected void btnSub_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GetRandom();
        if (number2 > number1)
        {
            answer = number2 - number1;
            lblEquation.Text = number2.ToString() + " - " + number1.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            answer = number1 - number2;
            lblEquation.Text = number1.ToString() + " - " + number2.ToString();
        }
        Session["answer"] = answer;

    }//END Subtraction Button

    protected void btnMult_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GetRandom();
        lblEquation.Text = number1.ToString() + " x " + number2.ToString();
        answer = number1 * number2;
        Session["answer"] = answer;
    }//END Multiplication Button

    protected void btnDiv_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Random rand = new Random();
        number1 = rand.Next(1, 10);
        number2 = rand.Next(1, 10);
        /*will only display the txtRemainder(textbox) while using the Divide button,
           txtRemainder will auto-hide when using another button because
           it's default setting of '.Visible = false' is placed in the Page_Load*/
        txtRemainder.Visible = true;
        lblEquation.Text = number1.ToString() + " / " + number2.ToString(); 
        answer = number1 / number2;
        Session["answer"] = answer;

    }//END Division Button

    protected void btnCheck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblYesNo.Text = "";
        //default int values are set to 0
        int remainder = 0;
        int guess = 0;

        remainder = int.Parse(txtRemainder.Text);

        guess = int.Parse(txtAnswer.Text);
        answer = (int)Session["answer"];
        if (guess == answer)
        {
            lblYesNo.Text = lblYesNo.Text + "Correct!";
        }
        else
        {
            lblYesNo.Text = lblYesNo.Text + "Try Again..";
        }
    }//END Check Answer
}
```

If this question doesn't make sense please ask for clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question 1:

Yes, that is the correct way to initialize your variables to default values of zero, although `int` variables are initialized to zero by default, so even if you omitted the assignment, they would still default to zero.

The method you're using to accept the user input is correct, but could throw an exception if the values entered by the user are not Int32 values (think 3.2). As it stands, you have no try..catch blocks to deal with these exceptions. You could either add these try..catch blocks, or you could use the TryParse() method to check that the values are valid. For example:

```
protected void btnCheck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblYesNo.Text = "";
    //default int values are set to 0
    int remainder = 0;
    int guess = 0;

    if (!Int32.TryParse(txtRemainder.Text, out remainder))
    {
        // do something here to inform the user that remainder is invalid
        return;
    }

    if (!Int32.TryParse(txtAnswer.Text, out remainder))
    {
        // do something here to inform the user that answer is invalid
        return;
    }

    answer = (int)Session["answer"];
    if (guess > answer)
    {
        lblYesNo.Text = lblYesNo.Text + "Try Again..";
    }
    else if (guess < answer)
    {
        lblYesNo.Text = lblYesNo.Text + "Try Again..";
    }
    else
    {
        lblYesNo.Text = lblYesNo.Text + "Correct!";
    }
}//END Check Answer
```

TryParse() will convert the value into the output variable if it's a valid value & return `true` to indicate success, otherwise it will return `false` if it was not able to perform the conversion.

Question 2:

In order to hide `txtRemainder` when the page first loads & then to keep it hidden if any button was clicked other than `btnDiv`, here is a proposed solution. First, the code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack) {
        lblTest.Visible = false;
    } else {
        foreach (string ctrl in Request.Form) {
            Control c = FindControl(ctrl);
            if (c is Button) {
                txtRemainder.Visible = c.ID == "btnDiv";
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now for some explaining. When the page initially loads, the label is hidden (by the `!IsPostBack` check). If the request is indeed a postback, we go through the collection of returned form controls (contained in the `Request.Form` collection) & check to see if a button is present that could have caused the postback. Buttons are rendered in the HTML as `<input type="submit" .. />` elements, and upon postback, only the button that was clicked is sent back in the `Form` collection, even if there are multiple submits on the page. A more detailed explanation can be found [here](http://ryanfarley.com/blog/archive/2005/03/11/1886.aspx)

Now, if a button did indeed cause the postback, then we check to see if this button was `btnDiv`. If it was, the comparison returns `true` & `txtRemainder` is displayed. If not, it is hidden.

This way, there is no need to show or hide `txtRemainder` in each event handlers. You wouldn't even need to set it to visible in the event handler for `btnDiv`.

**EDIT**

Based on the requirement listed in the comments, I've altered my answer to question 2 so as to provide an alternative method to having to show or hide the label in each button event.

Comment: Thanks for Q1 help, this is only for school project so I don't need to make it work perfect, but that explains it for sure.

Comment: Happy to help. The closer you can get your code to perfect, the better. :) Code as defensively as you can & handle as many fringe scenarios as possible. That'll make your applications more stable & keep your users informed. Just because it's a school project doesn't mean you shouldn't make it as solid as possible. Best of luck!

Comment: As for Q2, if I set it to `.visible = true` it will make the textbox become visible for every answer (Addition, Subtraction and Multiply equations). I only want it to remain visible during Division problems...

<IN MY HEAD>
`if (division problem)
{
   txtRemainder.Visible = true;
}
else
{
   txtRemainder.Visible = false;
}`

Comment: My apologies. I noticed after posting my initial answer that you're working with ASP.NET. I've edited my response to reflect an alternative solution.

Comment: so it does work as expected but my problem is, if I move back to another problem (add sub mult) the txtRemainder doesn't default back to hidden...should I just add a `txtRemainder.Visible = false;` to all the other buttons? If so then it would be useless to have it as 'false' in the first place because I can just bring it up at the Divide button and hide it on all other buttons. (which would work too, but I was going for a "less code" and more "by event" style)

Comment: Not at all, you have a valid point. I've altered my answer to Question 2 above with a possible solution to your requirements. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

**Question1:**
If you are using .Net 4.0 and up, consider using the `TryParse` method, and check the result for success, this way you have better control over parsing values and trapping exceptions
e.g.

```
int number = 0;
bool result = false;

result = int.TryParse("123", out number);

if (!result)
{
    throw new InvalidCastException("Error converting number");
}
```

**Question2:**
It looks like you're using Asp.Net, so try testing for `Page.IsPostBack` in your Page_Load event, this way you can determine whether the page loads because of an initial load, or because you sent data to the server i.e. clicked a button.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Q1) answer makes sense. Thanks.

======
Q2) I'm not that far in C# yet...I have no idea what `Page.IsPostBack` means or does...but thanks anyway

Comment: Page.IsPostBack is a flag that indicates whether the request was made as a postback, i.e. after the page has initially loaded. So in your case, you only want to hide the TextBox when the page initially loads. To do this, your wrap your code in a !Page.IsPostBack check, as illustrated in James & my answer.

Comment: thank you. I actually looked it up but now it makes sense. To be more specific I only want it to SHOW when doing division problems and hide it for everything else...but I managed to get that down too.